# zabbix agent : cannot accept incoming connection for peer: frontend

Tags: zabbix

Im running a zabbix agent on my server and i have this problem with it : when the server tries to connect to it i get the following error message in /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.log :

```
2022/06/30 18:35:38.627607 cannot accept incoming connection for peer: 172.16.238.2
2022/06/30 18:35:52.433324 [101] In refreshActiveChecks() from [172.16.239.40:10051]
2022/06/30 18:35:52.433379 connecting to [172.16.239.40:10051] [timeout:3s, connection timeout:3s]
2022/06/30 18:35:52.433616 sending [{"request":"active checks","host":"Zabbix server","version":"6.0"}] to [172.16.239.40:10051]
2022/06/30 18:35:52.433971 receiving data from [172.16.239.40:10051]
2022/06/30 18:35:52.451945 received [{"response":"success","data":[]}] from [172.16.239.40:10051]
2022/06/30 18:35:52.452089 [101] End of refreshActiveChecks() from [172.16.239.40:10051]
2022/06/30 18:35:52.452104 [101] processing update request (0 requests)
2022/06/30 18:35:52.452109 [101] skipping empty update for unregistered client
2022/06/30 18:36:38.672626 cannot accept incoming connection for peer: 172.16.238.2
```

You notice this is a problem with the frontend (172.16.238.2), but the backend is ok (172.16.239.40).

How can i resolve this ? I have tried to set DebugLevel=5 to have more details but it's the same.

Both agent and server are on the same host machine.

This is my conf file (pretty much default except server ip)

```
############ GENERAL PARAMETERS #################

### Option: PidFile
#   Name of PID file.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# PidFile=/tmp/zabbix_agent2.pid

PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.pid
DebugLevel=5
### Option: LogType
#   Specifies where log messages are written to:
#       system  - syslog
#       file    - file specified with LogFile parameter
#       console - standard output
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogType=file

### Option: LogFile
#   Log file name for LogType 'file' parameter.
#
# Mandatory: yes, if LogType is set to file, otherwise no
# Default:
# LogFile=/tmp/zabbix_agent2.log

LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.log

### Option: LogFileSize
#   Maximum size of log file in MB.
#   0 - disable automatic log rotation.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1024
# Default:
# LogFileSize=1

LogFileSize=0

### Option: DebugLevel
#   Specifies debug level:
#   0 - basic information about starting and stopping of Zabbix processes
#   1 - critical information
#   2 - error information
#   3 - warnings
#   4 - for debugging (produces lots of information)
#   5 - extended debugging (produces even more information)
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-5
# Default:
# DebugLevel=3

### Option: SourceIP
#   Source IP address for outgoing connections.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# SourceIP=

##### Passive checks related

### Option: Server
#   List of comma delimited IP addresses, optionally in CIDR notation, or DNS names of Zabbix servers and Zabbix proxies.
#   Incoming connections will be accepted only from the hosts listed here.
#   If IPv6 support is enabled then '127.0.0.1', '::127.0.0.1', '::ffff:127.0.0.1' are treated equally
#   and '::/0' will allow any IPv4 or IPv6 address.
#   '0.0.0.0/0' can be used to allow any IPv4 address.
#   Example: Server=172.16.239.40,192.168.1.0/24,::1,2001:db8::/32,zabbix.example.com
#
# Mandatory: yes, if StartAgents is not explicitly set to 0
# Default:
# Server=

Server=172.16.239.40

### Option: ListenPort
#   Agent will listen on this port for connections from the server.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1024-32767
# Default:
# ListenPort=10050

### Option: ListenIP
#   List of comma delimited IP addresses that the agent should listen on.
#   First IP address is sent to Zabbix server if connecting to it to retrieve list of active checks.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ListenIP=0.0.0.0

### Option: StatusPort
#   Agent will listen on this port for HTTP status requests.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1024-32767
# Default:
# StatusPort=

##### Active checks related

### Option: ServerActive
#   List of comma delimited IP addresses or DNS names (address:port) pairs or clusters (address:port;address2:port) of Zabbix servers and Zabbix proxies for active checks.
#   If port is not specified, default port is used.
#   Cluster nodes need be separated by semicolon.
#   IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in square brackets if port for that host is specified.
#   If port is not specified, square brackets for IPv6 addresses are optional.
#   If this parameter is not specified, active checks are disabled.
#   Example for multiple servers:
#       ServerActive=172.16.239.40:20051,zabbix.domain,[::1]:30051,::1,[12fc::1]
#   Example for HA:
#       ServerActive=zabbix.cluster.node1;zabbix.cluster.node2:20051;zabbix.cluster.node3
#   Example for HA with two clusters and one server:
#       ServerActive=zabbix.cluster.node1;zabbix.cluster.node2:20051,zabbix.cluster2.node1;zabbix.cluster2.node2,zabbix.domain
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ServerActive=

ServerActive=172.16.239.40

### Option: Hostname
#   List of comma delimited unique, case sensitive hostnames.
#   Required for active checks and must match hostnames as configured on the server.
#   Value is acquired from HostnameItem if undefined.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Hostname=

Hostname=Zabbix server

### Option: HostnameItem
#   Item used for generating Hostname if it is undefined. Ignored if Hostname is defined.
#   Does not support UserParameters or aliases.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# HostnameItem=system.hostname

### Option: HostMetadata
#   Optional parameter that defines host metadata.
#   Host metadata is used at host auto-registration process.
#   An agent will issue an error and not start if the value is over limit of 255 characters.
#   If not defined, value will be acquired from HostMetadataItem.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-255 characters
# Default:
# HostMetadata=

### Option: HostMetadataItem
#   Optional parameter that defines an item used for getting host metadata.
#   Host metadata is used at host auto-registration process.
#   During an auto-registration request an agent will log a warning message if
#   the value returned by specified item is over limit of 255 characters.
#   This option is only used when HostMetadata is not defined.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# HostMetadataItem=

### Option: HostInterface
#   Optional parameter that defines host interface.
#   Host interface is used at host auto-registration process.
#   An agent will issue an error and not start if the value is over limit of 255 characters.
#   If not defined, value will be acquired from HostInterfaceItem.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-255 characters
# Default:
# HostInterface=

### Option: HostInterfaceItem
#   Optional parameter that defines an item used for getting host interface.
#   Host interface is used at host auto-registration process.
#   During an auto-registration request an agent will log a warning message if
#   the value returned by specified item is over limit of 255 characters.
#   This option is only used when HostInterface is not defined.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# HostInterfaceItem=

### Option: RefreshActiveChecks
#   How often list of active checks is refreshed, in seconds.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 60-3600
# Default:
# RefreshActiveChecks=120

### Option: BufferSend
#   Do not keep data longer than N seconds in buffer.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-3600
# Default:
# BufferSend=5

### Option: BufferSize
#   Maximum number of values in a memory buffer. The agent will send
#   all collected data to Zabbix Server or Proxy if the buffer is full.
#   Option is not valid if EnablePersistentBuffer=1
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 2-65535
# Default:
# BufferSize=100

### Option: EnablePersistentBuffer
#   Enable usage of local persistent storage for active items.
#   0 - disabled, in-memory buffer is used (default); 1 - use persistent buffer
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1
# Default:
# EnablePersistentBuffer=0

### Option: PersistentBufferPeriod
#   Zabbix Agent2 will keep data for this time period in case of no
#   connectivity with Zabbix server or proxy. Older data will be lost. Log data will be preserved.
#   Option is valid if EnablePersistentBuffer=1
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1m-365d
# Default:
# PersistentBufferPeriod=1h

### Option: PersistentBufferFile
#   Full filename. Zabbix Agent2 will keep SQLite database in this file.
#   Option is valid if EnablePersistentBuffer=1
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# PersistentBufferFile=

############ ADVANCED PARAMETERS #################

### Option: Alias
#   Sets an alias for an item key. It can be used to substitute long and complex item key with a smaller and simpler one.
#   Multiple Alias parameters may be present. Multiple parameters with the same Alias key are not allowed.
#   Different Alias keys may reference the same item key.
#   For example, to retrieve the ID of user 'zabbix':
#   Alias=zabbix.userid:vfs.file.regexp[/etc/passwd,^zabbix:.:([0-9]+),,,,\1]
#   Now shorthand key zabbix.userid may be used to retrieve data.
#   Aliases can be used in HostMetadataItem but not in HostnameItem parameters.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range:
# Default:

### Option: Timeout
#   Spend no more than Timeout seconds on processing
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-30
# Default:
# Timeout=3

### Option: Include
#   You may include individual files or all files in a directory in the configuration file.
#   Installing Zabbix will create include directory in /usr/local/etc, unless modified during the compile time.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Include=

Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.d/*.conf

# Include=/usr/local/etc/zabbix_agent2.userparams.conf
# Include=/usr/local/etc/zabbix_agent2.conf.d/
# Include=/usr/local/etc/zabbix_agent2.conf.d/*.conf

### Option:PluginTimeout
#   Timeout for connections with external plugins.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-30
# Default: <Global timeout>
# PluginTimeout=

### Option:PluginSocket
#   Path to unix socket for external plugin communications.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:/tmp/agent.plugin.sock
# PluginSocket=

####### USER-DEFINED MONITORED PARAMETERS #######

### Option: UnsafeUserParameters
#   Allow all characters to be passed in arguments to user-defined parameters.
#   The following characters are not allowed:
#   \ ' " ` * ? [ ] { } ~ $ ! & ; ( ) < > | # @
#   Additionally, newline characters are not allowed.
#   0 - do not allow
#   1 - allow
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1
# Default:
# UnsafeUserParameters=0

### Option: UserParameter
#   User-defined parameter to monitor. There can be several user-defined parameters.
#   Format: UserParameter=<key>,<shell command>
#   See 'zabbix_agentd' directory for examples.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# UserParameter=

### Option: UserParameterDir
#   Directory to execute UserParameter commands from. Only one entry is allowed.
#   When executing UserParameter commands the agent will change the working directory to the one
#   specified in the UserParameterDir option.
#   This way UserParameter commands can be specified using the relative ./ prefix.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# UserParameterDir=

### Option: ControlSocket
#   The control socket, used to send runtime commands with '-R' option.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ControlSocket=

ControlSocket=/tmp/agent.sock

####### TLS-RELATED PARAMETERS #######

### Option: TLSConnect
#   How the agent should connect to server or proxy. Used for active checks.
#   Only one value can be specified:
#       unencrypted - connect without encryption
#       psk         - connect using TLS and a pre-shared key
#       cert        - connect using TLS and a certificate
#
# Mandatory: yes, if TLS certificate or PSK parameters are defined (even for 'unencrypted' connection)
# Default:
# TLSConnect=unencrypted

### Option: TLSAccept
#   What incoming connections to accept.
#   Multiple values can be specified, separated by comma:
#       unencrypted - accept connections without encryption
#       psk         - accept connections secured with TLS and a pre-shared key
#       cert        - accept connections secured with TLS and a certificate
#
# Mandatory: yes, if TLS certificate or PSK parameters are defined (even for 'unencrypted' connection)
# Default:
# TLSAccept=unencrypted

### Option: TLSCAFile
#   Full pathname of a file containing the top-level CA(s) certificates for
#   peer certificate verification.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSCAFile=

### Option: TLSCRLFile
#   Full pathname of a file containing revoked certificates.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSCRLFile=

### Option: TLSServerCertIssuer
#       Allowed server certificate issuer.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSServerCertIssuer=

### Option: TLSServerCertSubject
#       Allowed server certificate subject.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSServerCertSubject=

### Option: TLSCertFile
#   Full pathname of a file containing the agent certificate or certificate chain.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSCertFile=

### Option: TLSKeyFile
#   Full pathname of a file containing the agent private key.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSKeyFile=

### Option: TLSPSKIdentity
#   Unique, case sensitive string used to identify the pre-shared key.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSPSKIdentity=

### Option: TLSPSKFile
#   Full pathname of a file containing the pre-shared key.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSPSKFile=

####### PLUGIN-SPECIFIC PARAMETERS #######

### Option: Plugins
#   A plugin can have one or more plugin specific configuration parameters in format:
#     Plugins.<PluginName>.<Parameter1>=<value1>
#     Plugins.<PluginName>.<Parameter2>=<value2>
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range:
# Default:

### Option: Plugins.Log.MaxLinesPerSecond
#   Maximum number of new lines the agent will send per second to Zabbix Server
#   or Proxy processing 'log' and 'logrt' active checks.
#   The provided value will be overridden by the parameter 'maxlines',
#   provided in 'log' or 'logrt' item keys.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-1000
# Default:
# Plugins.Log.MaxLinesPerSecond=20

### Option: AllowKey
#   Allow execution of item keys matching pattern.
#   Multiple keys matching rules may be defined in combination with DenyKey.
#   Key pattern is wildcard expression, which support "*" character to match any number of any characters in certain position. It might be used in both key name and key arguments.
#   Parameters are processed one by one according their appearance order.
#   If no AllowKey or DenyKey rules defined, all keys are allowed.
#
# Mandatory: no

### Option: DenyKey
#   Deny execution of items keys matching pattern.
#   Multiple keys matching rules may be defined in combination with AllowKey.
#   Key pattern is wildcard expression, which support "*" character to match any number of any characters in certain position. It might be used in both key name and key arguments.
#   Parameters are processed one by one according their appearance order.
#   If no AllowKey or DenyKey rules defined, all keys are allowed.
#       Unless another system.run[*] rule is specified DenyKey=system.run[*] is added by default.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# DenyKey=system.run[*]

### Option: Plugins.SystemRun.LogRemoteCommands
#   Enable logging of executed shell commands as warnings.
#   0 - disabled
#   1 - enabled
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Plugins.SystemRun.LogRemoteCommands=0

### Option: ForceActiveChecksOnStart
#   Perform active checks immediately after restart for first received configuration.
#   Also available as per plugin configuration, example: Plugins.Uptime.System.ForceActiveChecksOnStart=1
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1
# Default:
# ForceActiveChecksOnStart=0

# Include configuration files for plugins
Include=./zabbix_agent2.d/plugins.d/*.conf
```

Comment: check the local firewall, and selinux

Comment: the firewall is not involved since it's on the same machine, and anyway the port is open. i dont think i have selinux enabled, it s a debian 11 distrib

Comment: selinux is not installed

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put both backend and frontend ip adresses in the `server=` and `serveractive=` in the conf file
In my case :

```
Server=172.16.239.40, 172.16.238.2
ServerActive=172.16.239.40, 172.16.238.2
```